# Dynamically loading html with image in using xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i got a problem in creating dynamicia html by using pure javascript. I create one index.html  and dynamically load image with xmlhttp.

```
var ajaxRemote = function (xmlhttp, url, callback) {
try {
   //my ajax function
}
catch (e) {
    debugger;
}
```

}
then handle the response data.

```
  for (; x < preImgNum; x++) {
                allImageLength++;
                var tmpImg = new Image(); 
                tmpImg.src = data[x][imgPath];
                //then append the tmpImg may be lots

            }
```

This ajaxRemote function is binded by window.onload.So it will be called everytime in page refresh and the images will be loaded again.It will be a long time loading when the remote server return 
me large datas .

But when i browse other image sites ,the long time loading only exists first time,if i refresh the web,it
can display all the images without any waiting.

It comes to my problems,Does this one  images caching tech,or
it is only that because  the page created by php and java .Appreciate for everyone.

Comment: It may be because the browser caches the images on local computer. Try to clear your browser cache to confirm.

Comment: Thanks first.I do what you said and it become a long time loading again.But the new problem is why the browser do not cache my images.